# How to link image in the article to image itself by default in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there anyway i can set the image link by default to the post itself?
I don't want to set the image link in the media up loader every time.
My code that gets content for post is this:

```
                        <?php if (!$is_paged && $archives == "false") { ?>
                            <?php woo_image('class=thumbnail&width='.get_option('woo_home_thumb_width').'&height='.get_option('woo_home_thumb_height')); ?> 
                            <div class="post-title">
                                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <p class="post-details"><?php _e('Posted on',woothemes); ?> <?php the_time('d. M, Y'); ?> <?php _e('by',woothemes); ?>  <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>.</p>

                            </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php woo_image('class=alignleft thumbnail&width='.get_option('woo_thumb_width').'&height='.get_option('woo_thumb_height')); ?> 
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="post-details"><?php _e('Posted on',woothemes); ?> <?php the_time('d. M, Y'); ?> <?php _e('by',woothemes); ?>  <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>.</p>
                          <!--  <div class="comment-cloud">
                                <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?></a>
                            </div> -->
                        <?php } ?> <?php global $more; $more = 0;?>

                        <?php if ( get_option('woo_content') == "true" ) { the_content('Read More >>'); } else { the_excerpt();?><?php } ?>


                    </div> 
                    <!-- Normal Post Ends -->
```

What i do is post an image with some lines below it and the insert a read more tag.
Is there a way i can use first image in the post and link to the article, just as the title does?

Comment: you want an image clickable or waht ?

Comment: yes i want my image clickable to the post itself.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to link the images of the article to the article itself? Why would the user want to be taken to the page he is already on?

Comment: @Rao , in the front page i use blog posts with image and few lines with a read more link, So i need it because whether user clicks on the image or the title ,it has to to go to single page post.

Answer (score 0):

At top of the page

```
<?php
global $post;
global $wpdb;

?>
```

---

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" >
      <img src="your_source_here" title="image" />
</a>
```

`get_parmalink();` will take you to the detail page of the post respectively.

Comment: I get contents from the function 'the_content()' , so how can i change the anchor reference to the permalink.

Comment: Check my answer I have changed the anchor link what you want to do

Comment: where do i change the anchor link.Check my question i have posted the code.